the procedure entry point hb_ot_tags_from_script_and_language could not be located in the dynamic link library ...libfreetype-6.dll
I'm developing an application on windows that manipulates images.
I'm using msys2/ucrt64 version of gcc for compiling and msys2/ucrt64 version of openimageio library for image import/export.
My code compiles and links but on execution I've got the error:

procedure entry point hb_ot_tags_from_script_and_language could not be located in the dynamic link library ...libfreetype-6.dll

and many similar error, all related to harfbuzz library symbols (which is also installed as a msys2/ucrt64 package), used in various dll whose openimageio depends on.
I found a few mentions of this issue on the web but no solution was provided.
Path to msys2 packages dll is on my user environment path.
I tried the suggested solutions in How to debug DLL issues in MinGW?, namely running inside MSYS2 terminal or in a windows terminal with msys64\ucrt64\bin directory at the top of the path, but the result is exactly the same.
AFAIK all package in my msys2 installation are up to date.
Is there a way to fix that?

Does this answer your question: How to debug DLL issues in MinGW?

In particular, move the MSYS2 installation to the beginning of system-wide PATH to give it the most priority. Or try running the exe from the MSYS2 terminal, which automatically sets the correct PATH for itself.

@HolyBlackCat though the linked question and its answer is interesting, it does not solve the issue (tried MSYS2 terminal and cmd terminal with updated path)

Can you please open a terminal (non MSYS2), print PATH in it (echo $env:PATH in powershell) and confirm that C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin is the first directory in it?

@HolyBlackCat Damn you're right the PATH is starting with system path, not user path. in cmd, I even get miniconda3/condabin prepended to all paths... I've just updated system path and reopened terminals (PATH now starts with msys64\ucrt64\bin) but same behavior
